# Why does Kotlin crash passing generic Result parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I appear to have a situation where the compile time and run time types of a `Result<T>` parameter are different, causing a `ClassCastException` at run time.

I updated my Android Studio Kotlin plugin version to the latest, 1.4.31, and my app began crashing. The crash did not happen with the previous version, 1.4.21. Am I misusing the Result type generics and just got lucky it worked in 1.4.21? Is this a compiler bug? The crash started with 1.4.30.

Here is sample code to reproduce the crash:

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var button: MaterialButton
    private var resultTest: TestService<String>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button = findViewById(R.id.do_it_button)
        button.setOnClickListener { startTest() }
    }

    private fun startTest() {

        resultTest = TestService()

        resultTest?.callMeBack("This is a test") { param ->
            val str = param.getOrNull() /* <<< line 25, site of crash */
            button.text = str
        }
    }
}
```

**TestService.kt:**

```
class TestService<T> {

    fun interface CompletionHandler<T> {
        fun onFinished(result: Result<T>)
    }

    fun <T> callMeBack(value: T, completion: CompletionHandler<T>) {
        val param = Result.success(value)
        completion.onFinished(param)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/do_it_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Do it!"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

When the "Do it!" button is tapped the app crashes with:

```
2021-03-26 09:23:06.851 21628-21628/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 21628
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to kotlin.Result
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$startTest$1.onFinished(MainActivity.kt:25)
        at com.example.myapplication.TestService.callMeBack(TestService.kt:11)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startTest(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.access$startTest(MainActivity.kt:7)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        ...
```

The crash is on the line

```
val str = param.getOrNull()
```

It's as though param received by the completion callback is actually a `String`, not a `Result<String>`.

If I change `ext.kotlin_version` to 1.4.21 it runs fine.

Comment: Are you using the new jvm IR backend? There's a known bug when using the new IR, inline Result is not unboxed: see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44837 and https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/554910f6083664d3de41b485fd3c71d96b55eb37

Comment: I'm not using the IR backend, just the standard Android Studio Gradle plugin. Since posting this SO I raised the issue in YouTrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45810 and it appears to have been triaged and accepted as a bug.

Interestingly given your comment the triage note was that my problem was confirmed as an issue in 1.4.32 but does _not_ occur using the IR backend.