# Result nested twice when collecting a Flow in Kotlin 1.5 (kotlin.Result cannot be cast to `Type`)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Recently I've updated my project to **Kotlin 1.5** and noticed some weird and unexpected behaviour when combining `Flow` with `Result`. Consider the following example:

```kotlin
// Kotlin 1.5.0
// Coroutines (kotlinx-coroutines-core) 1.5.0

class Foo

interface FooListener {
    fun onSuccess(foo: Foo)
    fun onFailure(error: Throwable?)
}

suspend fun collectData(listener: FooListener) {
    flow { emit(Result.success(Foo())) }
        .collect { result -> // for reference
            when {
                result.isSuccess -> listener.onSuccess(result.getOrThrow())
                result.isFailure -> listener.onFailure(result.exceptionOrNull())
            }
        }
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        collectData(object : FooListener {
            override fun onSuccess(foo: Foo) {
                println(foo)
            }

            override fun onFailure(error: Throwable?) {
                println(error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The above compiles but fails in runtime with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Result cannot be cast to Foo
```

After some debugging I noticed that the collected value (`result`) appears to be of type `Result<Result<Foo>>` instead of the expected `Result<Foo>`:

```kotlin
suspend fun collectData(listener: FooListener) {
    flow { emit(Result.success(Foo())) }
        .collect { result ->
            println(result) // Output: Success(Success(Foo@...))
            when {
                result.isSuccess -> listener.onSuccess(result.getOrThrow())
                result.isFailure -> listener.onFailure(result.exceptionOrNull())
            }
        }
}
```

The problem disappears when I give up an idea of using externally provided listeners or callback functions in `collectData` and, for example, use something defined globally:

```kotlin
class Foo

interface FooListener {
    fun onSuccess(foo: Foo)
    fun onFailure(error: Throwable?)
}

val listener = object : FooListener {
    override fun onSuccess(foo: Foo) {
        println(foo)
    }

    override fun onFailure(error: Throwable?) {
        println(error)
    }
}

suspend fun collectData() {
    flow { emit(Result.success(Foo())) }
        .collect { result ->
            println(result) // Output: Success(Foo@...)
            when {
                result.isSuccess -> listener.onSuccess(result.getOrThrow())
                result.isFailure -> listener.onFailure(result.exceptionOrNull())
            }
        }
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        collectData()
    }
}
```

The above runs without any errors.

---

At this point it seems to me like a bug in the language, but I've been onto this for so long I'm not 100% sure and I could use a second opinion before bringing it up on Kotlin YouTrack.

I've seen [Why does Kotlin crash passing generic Result parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66814634/11342519) and [JVM / IR: ClassCastException with Result object when it is used by a generic method in a suspend call](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44837) but the bug not only looks the other way around, but it is supposed to be fixed in the newest version as well.

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug, when switching to `1.4.32`, the code runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Does the bug still happen if you give the Flow builder an explicit type like `flow<Result<Foo>> { ... }`?

Comment: @BrianYencho yes, setting an explicit type anywhere makes no difference.

Comment: Apparently I didn't dig deep enough and there's a similar issue already reported ([KT-46477](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46477)), which I believe has the same root cause. Thank you @HenryTwist for looking into it.

Comment: Have same problem, maybe this is related to
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tracked in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46915 and looks like the fix will be released with Kotlin 1.5.30

Comment: I checked it with 1.5.30-M1, indeed the issue seems to be gone. Thanks for looking into that :)

Answer (score 1):

I have The same issue I downgraded the kotlin version from `1.5.10` to `1.4.32` and the code run correctly.